# How do I implement a 410 header in .htaccess to remove hacked URLs?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, robots.txt, http-status-code-410

My site got hacked recently and has over 3 million pages now when it only has 30 pages (see screenshot).

How do I implement the correct 410 header in `.htaccess`?

I think the best tactic is to 410 all pages that contain a number OR .htm OR `.html` as none of the real pages have these in the URL. For example -

- `https://example.com/cixc-20050gsakuramar/-b00006.htm`
- `https://example.com/sfumato.php?nzlw-21833vetidm4`
- `https://example.com/bzmt-5694ceti.html`
- `https://example.com/pfks-14602sjp/ucqksti.htm`
- `https://example.com/admv-15974mitem/318`

Would this code work?

```
Redirect 410 /*0*
Redirect 410 /*1*
Redirect 410 /*2*
Redirect 410 /*3*
Redirect 410 /*4*
Redirect 410 /*5*
Redirect 410 /*6*
Redirect 410 /*7*
Redirect 410 /*8*
Redirect 410 /*9*
Redirect 410 /*.html*
Redirect 410 /*.htm*
```

I've also pieced together a rewrite rule which might also work?

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ - [G,L]
```

I am also thinking of adding Disallow to `robots.txt` like this -

```
Disallow: /*0*
Disallow: /*1*
Disallow: /*2*
Disallow: /*3*
Disallow: /*4*
Disallow: /*5*
Disallow: /*6*
Disallow: /*7*
Disallow: /*8*
Disallow: /*9*
Disallow: /*.htm
Disallow: /*.html
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [redirect directive of mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) doesn't support wild cards.   So your rules such as `Redirect 410 /*0*` would not do what you expect.  You could make them into `RedirectMatch` directives which support regular expressions.  I'd combine all the numbers into one rule, and html suffixes into another:

```bash
RedirectMatch Gone ".*[0-9].*" 
RedirectMatch Gone ".*\.html?$"
```

From your Google Search Console screenshot, it looks like some of the URLS have query strings in them with a `?`.  `mod_alias` doesn't consult the query string at all when matching the URL.  If the `.html` appears in the query string and not in the URL path, `RedirectMatch` won't be able to match it.

I'd recommend going with `mod_rewrite` rules which can match the query string.  Another reason to prefer .htaccess would be if you have other rewrite rules in your `.htaccess`.  Additional rewrite rules would be less likely to conflict than mod_alias rules.

I've added a condition to skip `wp-content` URLs because in the comments, you say you actually have some CSS files with numbers in them.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?wp-content/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !pagespeed
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !fontawesome
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !webfont
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [0-9] - [G,L]
RewriteRule \.html?$ - [G,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !v(er)?=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [0-9]
RewriteRule . - [G,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.html?$
RewriteRule . - [G,L]
```

I wouldn't recommend using a `Disallow` in `robots.txt` because Google sometimes indexes disallowed URLs anyway even if it can't crawl them.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Stephen Ostermiller. I've added what you recommended like this to .htaccess -
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule [0-9] - [G,L]
RewriteRule \.html?$ - [G,L]
RewriteRule \.htm?$ - [G,L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: You'll need to put the `[G]` rules above your front controller rule.  In other words they need to come before you `index.php` rule.

Comment: Yes. You won't be able to remove based on numbers if you have actual CSS files with numbers like that.

Comment: I added a rewrite condition that should except `wp-content` URLs.

Comment: Hi @Stephen Ostermiller I added the new rewrite rule but it still 410's the CSS and JS :(

Comment: Try `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` instead of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?wp-content/`  (that should prevent that rule from executing if a file exists on disk with that name.)

Comment: Hi @Stephen Ostermiller  the assets still 410. Here's a screenshot in devtools - https://i.ibb.co/YZXGVMs/410.jpg I will send you an email I don't mind paying for your help and maybe you can help with some other stuff!

Comment: It looks like you need to add more exceptions, or abandon your rule that shows 410 for any URL with a number.  I edited in exceptions for `pagespeed` and `ver=` but you may find more.

Comment: Hi @StephenOstermiller thanks so much for your help. Nearly there!! The only thing that its 410 now is fontawesome, icons aren't loading. I tried adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !fontawesome` and`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !webfont` but it didn't work. Any ideas how to fix please? Here's a screenshot - https://i.ibb.co/zGbZ9Zz/fa.jpg

Comment: Those are going to hit both of the number rules.  They need the exceptions you put in plus an exception for `v=` on the query string.  I put that into the `ver=` exception with `!v(er)?=`